# Скрытие и раскрытие строк в таблице кнопкой-ссылкой

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Доброго всем времени суток, господа.

Есть табличка. Выводится на PHP в цикле. В табличке строки мысленно можно разделить на 3 типа. Положение и последовательность заранее не известны. 1 тип - строки, которые трогать не нужно. 3 - выводятся всегда ниже 2х. Изначально, при выводе таблицы охота скрыть строки 3го типа, а в строках 2го типа сделать кнопку-ссылку (скажем, в отдельной ячейке) при нажатии на которую раскрываются/скрываются строки 3го типа.

Пример того, что выводится в цикле на PHP:

```
строка 01 тип 1
строка 02 тип 1
строка 03 тип 1
строка 04 тип 2
строка 05 тип 3
строка 06 тип 3
строка 07 тип 3
строка 08 тип 1
строка 09 тип 1
строка 10 тип 2
строка 11 тип 3
строка 12 тип 3
строка 13 тип 1
строка 14 тип 1
строка 15 тип 1
```

что охота видеть:

```
строка 01 тип 1
строка 02 тип 1
строка 03 тип 1
строка 04 тип 2 (при нажатии на кнопку-ссылку появляются/исчезают строки 05,06,07)
строка 08 тип 1
строка 09 тип 1
строка 10 тип 2 (при нажатии на кнопку-ссылку появляются/исчезают строки 11,12)
строка 13 тип 1
строка 14 тип 1
строка 15 тип 1
```

Подскажите, как реализовать данную задачу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рекурсия в помощь! На [стаке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909868/help-with-php-recursive-navigation-list-menu) в ответе пример реализации! + `Jquery` или родной `js` для реализации выпадающих пунктов.

Jquery:

```
$('.li').click(function(){
    $("ul", this).toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Неискусно. Но вполне должно работать. Если что, професcионалы подкорректируют.

```
$rows = getROWS();
//$rows[N] = array('text'=>_STRING,'property'=>array());

function preprocessRows(&$rows){
    $tmpRowNum = null;
    foreach($rows as $num=>$row){
        if($row['type']==2){
            $tmpRowNum = $num;
        }
        if($row['type']==3){
            if($tmpRowNum){// Защита от появления третьего ряда ДО второго.
                $rows[$tmpRowNum]['property'][] = $num;
            }
            $rows[$num]['property']['visibility'] = 'hidden';
        }
    }
}

//Вот теперь можно выводить:
preprocessRows($rows);

print('<table>');
foreach($rows as $num=>$row){
    $text = $row['text'];
    $property  = '';
    if($row['type']==2){
        $property  = 'onclick="toggle(#'.implode(',#',$row['property']).')"';
    }
    if($row['type']==3){
        $property  = 'style="visibility:hidden;"';
    }
    printf('<tr %s id="num%s"><td>%s</td></tr>',$property,$num,$text);
}
print('</table>');
```

То, что тут два цикла, не должно стать проблемой: суровая реальность такова, что на маленьких таблицах скорость не упадет вообще, а на больших(~1Мб+). В любом случае в браузере она разворачиваться будет на много дольше, чем в препроцессе.

Через один цикл это же реализовать возможно, если вывести ряд второго типа с `placeholder`, а потом в `placeholder` подставить список рядов, которые стоит скрывать.

Comment: @Iranda, молодец. =)